# getText() method throwing NullPointerException in Struts 2

Tags: java, properties, nullpointerexception, struts2, localization

I have a `package.properties` file which contains

```
email.domain=localhost:8080
```

Now, from a class inside the same package I am calling `getText("email.domain")` but getting this error:

**stacktrace:**

```
System.out.println("http://" + getText("email.domain") + "/ReportContent.action");

java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.LocalizedTextUtil.findText(LocalizedTextUtil.java:361)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.TextProviderSupport.getText(TextProviderSupport.java:208)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.TextProviderSupport.getText(TextProviderSupport.java:123)
        at   com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionSupport.getText(ActionSupport.java:103)
```

How to resolve the issue here?

Answer (score 0):

You can call `getText` *only* in the context of the action mapped to the request being executed in the current thread.

If you want to load properties you can use `Properties` class and method `load()`.

Comment: Can you please explain what do you mean by "context of the action mapped to the request being executed in the current thread"?

Comment: How did you call this method? Why didn't you post a full stacktrace?

Comment: What is the version of Struts?

Answer (score 0):

Below one is a typical Struts2 project created from Maven repository.

[image]

All my Action class's will be available in **com.xxx.controller** package.

To make it work of the getText("xxxxxx") method the following configurations need to be done.

1. Your actions should directly or indirectly extend the `ActionSupport` class
2. Along with struts.xml you should place `struts.properties` and `XXXXX.properties` file where you placed your struts.xml
3. The configurations in struts.properties is

> struts.custom.i18n.resources=<file name of additonal properties
>   file name without extension>
>   **Example** : struts.custom.i18n.resources=package.properties;

4. The configurations need to be done in struts.xml is:

> <constant name="struts.custon.i18n.resources"
>   value="XXXXX" />
>
> **Example** = <constant name="struts.custon.i18n.resources" value="package" />

Check you all these configurations properly configured in your project.

Answer (score 0):

`ActionSupport.getText()` eventually makes a call to `ActionContext.getContext().getValueStack()`.  Your NullPointer is because `ActionContext.getContext()` is null.  This can happen say when you create an ActionSupport object yourself ... perhaps by doing something like `ActionSupport myActionSupportObj = new ActionSupport()`;  Assuming the rest of your struts2 setup is complete, an appropriate way to get a working ActionSupport object is to override the AbstractInterceptor class

```
import com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionInvocation;
import com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionSupport;

public class MyInterceptor extends AbstractInterceptor {
    @Override
    public String intercept(ActionInvocation invocation) throws Exception {
        ActionSupport actionInstance = (ActionSupport) invocation.getAction();
```